# Personal preference on online data

Tags: android

Thanks in advance to all. I have a pretty good grip on basic android, and I want to start incorporating databases and online storage in my app. I want to host a simple online file/server/database (not to sure the terms) with six movie titles each with a title, image,  and show times. I am not looking for code as much as maybe some articles or topics you think I should read up on. Thanks again.